# Escaping dots and backslashes in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, special-characters

I develop a small rails app. It has a controller `books`. Route `/books/:title` shows a book with specified title.

The problem is that if book contains dots . or backslashes /, application returns either error `Record not found`, or routing error.

How to escape these characters, so that application can show such books correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found a solution. I added a route to include query strings for show action:

```
match '/show', :controller => 'books', :action => 'show'
```

It fixed my problem.